# How to transfer claims from WS-Federation reply into Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, ws-federation, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm pretty new to .net core 2.1, I figured if I'm going to build/rebuild a project I might as well use the new thing. So I've been fighting the ASP.NET Core Identity for a while - the documentation sure leaves something to be desired.

I have successfully implemented authentication - I redirect out to my ADFS and back again and users are logged in.

Then I began to look through Authorization. First I tried Role-Based but I have read that roles are not in much use, and besides I couldn't work out why roles assigned to users were failing the authorization checks (ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole and policies for razor pages).

I settled on using Claims-Based Authorization, figuring I could use the claims provided via WS-Federation - I'm sending a few (Name, Name ID, E-Mail Address, Group) where Group is the unqualified list of group memberships as strings - however, I don't see any of those claims on the ClaimsPrincipal (HttpContext.User) after login.

Breaking the flow during login I can see that call to

```
_signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()
```

is definitely getting the expected claims from ADFS, but isn't apparently getting through into whatever happens after that.

Like I said, I'm pretty hazy on how it works internally and TBH I don't really wanna get too deep into understanding the nitty gritty I just need to know that I can authorize based on group claims from ADFS.

My project is more-or-less the standard default asp.net core 2.1 website with the individual accounts authorization selected, then I added in the modifications for WS-Federation and jury rigged the Login action to redirect straight out to ADFS rather than prompt for it.

Please let me know if you need clarification, but the gist of it is:

**How do I get the group claims from ADFS into the ASP.NET Core Identity** so I can reference them in this manner:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminGroup", policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim("Group", "AD Admin Group Name")
                );
            });
```

Also, feel free to direct me at any answer I have missed. Been reading docs and searching the web for the entire day and not really progressed at all today!

Comment: I don't actually have a solution for my own question, but what I did instead was to completely disregard the ASP.NET Core Identity feature and use Ws-Federation directly as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-ws-federation-without-aspnet-core-identity). This allowed me to use User.Identity.Claims which is populated by the call out to ADFS with whatever claims I configured (in this case, groups).

Comment: Would you be willing to post the solution you came up with as an answer? I'm trying to do the same thing and have been unsuccessful thus far. In particular, I'm not able to access the claims after authentication, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I implemented almost exactly what is in the documentation I linked in my last comment. I'll add an 'answer' to outline it a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identitiy is working correctly. You just accessed the claims the wrong way. 
Try the following inside of a Razor Page.

```
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@{

  var claims = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User));
}
```

For policies you can use the class ClaimTypes in Startup.cs to get well known Claims
Ex.:

```
policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.WindowsAccountName));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This most answers my original question though I ended up going a different way :)

Answer (score 0):

To add extra information, here's the way I ended up circumventing the issue. The ASP.NET Core Identity feature was a lot more heavyweight than I wanted/needed, and the documentation was somewhat lacking. It also more-or-less hijacked the claims from the federation source and then replaced them with its own values. As I only needed to get the group claims sent by ADFS and use them in policies I did something like:

Remove ALL references to ASP.NET Core Identity. I don't remember what they are off the top of my head, but they should be pretty obvious to find.

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddWsFederation(options =>
        {
            options.MetadataAddress = "https://federationservicesurl/";
            options.Wtrealm = "realmname";
            options.SignOutWreply = "https://signoutaddress if you want it";

        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied"; // If you need one
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20); // Or from config
        });
```

This adds the authentication  options, ws-federation middleware, and cookies for it to work. Then you add Authorization:

```
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // Any Admins
            options.AddPolicy("RequireGroup", policy =>
                policy.RequireClaim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", "Group 1", "Group 2")
            );

            //... more policies
        }
```

and finally, you can use those policies. In my case I am using Razor Pages, so I just have a range of `AuthorizeFolder/AuthorizePage`.

```
services.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/AccessDenied");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/SignedOut");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/SignOut");

            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Network", "RequireGroup");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/About", "RequireGroup");

            // ... more directives
        })
```

And that just works. If you are wanting to also hide interface snippets you can do that. Again I'm using Razor and not pure MVC so I'm not sure how to implement this in the MVC way, but I do this in my cshtml file at the top:

```
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService
@{
    var requiregroup= (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "RequireGroup"));
}
```

and then:

```
@if (requiregroup.Succeeded)
{
    <div>some content that requires the policy RequireGroup</div>
}
```

Obviously, if you're hiding links/etc from a page you need to also have policies to prevent that user accessing the actual links since there's nothing stopping a user simply attempting to access any old path.

And that's how I implemented it. If anyone has any feedback to tell me I've done something horribly wrong I'm open to it :)

Comment: I won't put here how to configure WS-Federation in ADFS to actually send the claims. It's not really in the scope. It isn't too hard though - just google it.